# Make Img selected when clicked, like selectAll Text and show some menu in bottom of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

excuse me, im trying make some editor text with html, PHP and javascript only, and successfull inserting image on editor. but my problem is, when i click that image, the color of image dont changes like we selectAll text. here is the example of image that when select the color changes blue and menu show in bottom following where image appear

[example of my image inserted in blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKWTI.png)

ok that image example has inserted on my blog. when i click, it changes color into blue like a selected text. and menu show in bottom of these image, my real question is, how to make that menu appear follow the image position, and how to change the img color into blue when clicked?

i do some inspection using chrome and firefox for that menu, the dom of that menu is outside of iframe or editor and thats make me confuse because i only know the object follow for children only, but this, it appear and follow where image appear, is there have css access to make it follow even it dont inside that a img object?

i do some experiment to achieve it but fail, i also use code select() but show an error. i also try use execCommand but nothing show, except i put selectAll, the image selected but all text too. my goal is only select that image and show the menu in bottom like the example image i send before up there. thanks. and i hope my question is clear. oh and i need pure javascript only, no jquery. i hope i can make it.

**Edit** : well, before im success inserting image, and now im success make image selected using createRange(). and also now the image success show the menu when clicked and hide when the image clicked again. it also dont included when we submit the post.
now, my other problem is,is any solution for me via javascript? i mean, if we lost focus or click other place (when image selected and menu still show), the menu gone.we can say it lost focus etc, anywhere in page click make the menu hide again. i has try focus(), blur(), nothing changes. i also try window.selection().toString(). got same result. here is my code. until now im still think the solution and try many many times from 2 days ago.

```
var n = 0;
function insertingImage(sr, al, ttl, id) {
n++;
    var p= document.createElement('p');
    var p1 = document.createElement('p');
    var c = document.createElement('img');
    p.setAttribute("id", "myGmbr"+n);
    p.setAttribute("style", "margin:0;padding:0;text-align: center;-webkit-user-modify: read-only;");
    c.setAttribute("id", "gmbrPost"+n);
    c.setAttribute("class", "gmbrPost"+n);
    c.setAttribute('src', sr);
    c.setAttribute('alt', al);
    c.setAttribute('title', ttl);
    c.setAttribute('style', 'width:150px;height:150px;cursor: pointer;');
    uyaRichText.appendChild(p);
    p.appendChild(c);
    uyaRichText.appendChild(p1);
    p1.innerHTML = "<br>";
    var a = "myGmbr"+n;
    var a1 = "gmbrPost"+n;
    var ab = true;
    var an = document.getElementById("myGmbr"+n);
    var an1 = document.getElementById("gmbrPost"+n);
    var toggleOn = document.getElementById("myMenu");
    an.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(an);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    if(ab) {
        var pos = an1.getBoundingClientRect();
        var y = pos.top;
        var x = pos.left;
        var height = pos.height;
        toggleOn.style.left = x + pageXOffset+"px";
        toggleOn.style.top =  y + pageYOffset+ height+"px";//-pos.top+"px";
        toggleOn.style.display = "block";
        toggleOn.innerHTML= "<input type='button' class='small' value='Small'> <input type='button' class='medium' value='Medium'> <input type='button' class='large' value='Large'> <input type='button' class='original' value='Original'> | <input type='button' class='left' value='Left' onClick=\"moveImg('left', '"+a+"')\"> <input type='button' class='center' value='Center' onClick=\"moveImg('center', '"+a+"')\"> <input type='button' class='right' value='Right' onClick=\"moveImg('right', '"+a+"')\"> | <input type='button' class='alt-title' value='Alt - Title' onClick=\"titleAlt('"+a1+"','"+id+"')\">";
        ab = false;
    } else {
            toggleOn.style.display = "none";
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            ab = true;
        }
        });
}
```

any help solve this will appreciated. T_T

**Last Edit :** i found a solution for myself by trying lot of test. and finally made it complete using javascript.now i can insert an image and also select it to show menu, and then im also can move it by drag my mouse. thanks for all who view my question.